# Response cached from browser does not set cookies

Tags: caching, cookies, sveltekit

I am using a Svelte Kit server side only load function where a cookie is set and caching is enabled:

```
cookies.set('currentType', params.type, { path: '/path', maxAge: 3600, secure : false, httpOnly: false});

setHeaders({
  'Cache-Control': 'public, max-age=3600',
    // 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true,
    // 'Vary': 'Cookie'
});
```

The app is running on the vite dev server for now.

The answer from the server to the first request comes with the cookie header and the cookies are set. All subsequent requests are answered from the cache. According to chrome dev network tool the 'set cookies'  header is not included, according to firefox 'set cookies' is included in the answer from the cache.

The problem is that both browsers do not set the cookies when a request is answered from the cache.

I have already tried all combinations of `secure` and `httpOnly` within the `cookies.set` function. Within the `setHeaders` function I have tried `'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true` and `'Vary': 'Cookie'` as it was suggested by others. But nothing helped.

Thanks for an answer in advance.